# sharepoint file recovery

Tags: sharepoint-server, windows-server-2019

good day

I have a question I am switching from sharepoint server to sharepoint online but I have data on an unlinked mdf file or at least an old admin content but now my question is how do I get it off or is there a possibility to take it off

I would like to hear from you

Sincerely, Tobias Kasander

Comment: would you be able to provide which version of SP Server?

Comment: sharepoint server 2019 sorry I forgot to add it and sorry for the wrong response was very busy this week that I was going to respond quickly but that went wrong and that's why I responded in Dutch

Answer (score 0):

You need to stretch your PowerShell muscles :) Another option is to use a 3rd party app like ShareGate.

```
Get-SPContentDatabase -ConnectAsUnattachedDatabase  -DatabaseName <DatabaseName> -DatabaseServer <DatabaseServer>
```

It is explained on Microsoft Docs: [Restore content from unattached content databases in SharePoint Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/restore-content-from-an-unattached-content-database)

Here is another useful link:
[unattached content database recover contents list library](https://sharepointtechnicalsupport.com/unattached-content-database-recover-contents-list-library/)